# Problem separating variables (PDE)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE:

$$\nabla^2 u=-k^2u$$
where $k>0$.

The geometry demands cylindrical coordinates, which yields:
$$\frac{u_r}{r}+u_{rr}+\frac{u_{\varphi \varphi}}{r^2}+u_{zz}=-k^2u$$
So we're looking for a function:
$$u(r,\varphi,z)=R(r)Y(\varphi,z)$$
There's a  homogeneous boundary condition for $R(r_o)=0$, so separation of variables should be possible.
$$\frac{YR'}{r}+YR''+\frac{RY_{\varphi \varphi}}{r^2}+RY_{zz}=-k^2 RY$$
Divide both sides by $RY$:
$$\frac{R'}{rR}+\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{Y_{\varphi \varphi}}{r^2 Y}+\frac{Y_{zz}}{Y}=-k^2$$
But because the $r^2$ factor in the third denominator this is not separable?

I tried also this:
$$Y(\varphi,z)=\Phi(\varphi)Z(z)$$
$$\frac{Y_{\varphi \varphi}}{r^2 Y}=\frac{\Phi''}{r^2 \Phi}$$
$$\frac{Y_{zz}}{Y}=\frac{Z''}{Z}$$

But the problem remains. Is this not separable or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Why is it not separable? $u = R \Phi Z$ and solving leads to
$$ \frac{R'}{rR} + \frac{R''}{R} + \frac{\Phi''}{r^2 \Phi} = - k^2 - \frac{Z''}{Z} = \lambda $$
where $\lambda$ is the constant from separation of variables.

Comment: Oooopsie... I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{u_r}{r}+u_{rr}+\frac{u_{\varphi \varphi}}{r^2}+u_{zz}=-k^2u$$
$$u(r,\varphi,z)=R(r)P(\varphi)Z(z)$$
$$\frac{R'}{r}PZ+R''PZ+\frac{R}{r^2}P''Z+RPZ''=-k^2RPZ$$
$$\frac{R'}{rR}+\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{P''}{P}+\frac{Z''}{Z}=-k^2$$
This implies :
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{P''}{P}=\lambda=\text{constant} \\
\frac{Z''}{Z}=\mu=\text{constant} \\
\frac{R'}{rR}+\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{\lambda}{r^2}+\mu+k^2=0
\end{cases}$$
$P(\varphi)=c_1e^{\lambda\:\varphi}$

$Z(z)=c_2e^{\mu\:z}$

Solving for $R(r)$ the third equation $\quad R''+\frac{1}{r}R'+(\frac{\lambda}{r^2}+\mu+k^2)R=0\quad$
involves Bessel functions.